# What does "them" in stop 'em" refer to?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *The Suicide Squad* (2021), Rick Flag says to Sol Saria:

> Rick Flag: They're fucking idiots, but right now our objectives align
> with yours. If Jotunheim contains the technology our intelligence says
> it does, then it could be used on the people of Corto Maltese as well
> as Americans. That's why we need your help to get into the city so we
> can stop '**em**.

What does "them" in stop 'em" refer to?

Comment: I just looked at the subtitle file. In the half-dozen preceding (short) utterances, there are **4** references to ***they / them*** - plus an implied but unstated one in *Typical Americans. [**they**] Just run in, guns blazin*. Obviously "they" refers to the aforementioned ***fucking idiots***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "the people in Jotunheim",  that is "the people who could use the technology there on Americans".  Or more loosely it means "the enemy", "the people we are going to stop".